# Buffalo Linkstation(NAS) Joining Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, buffalo

I am using Windows Sever 2008. I have 2 Buffalo Linkstation and there are same problem.
Cannot to join Active Directory Domain

> Failed to join Active Directory Domain. Please confirm the Active
>   Directory Domain setting information, Administrator user name and
>   password.

I sure that all the input is correct. And the admin account, I tried to use the server computer admin account and other admin with domain admin right.
I think there is a permission problem in the server. But I dont know how to check and solve it. Any idea?

The setting page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working under the same subnet? Are Buffalo's dns pointing to your Win2008? Try also adding to Buffalo's in the WINS field, the IP of the server (may seems strange but I was able to let mine join by changing it)

Comment: Yes. I add the server IP at WINS field but there is same problem. The win2008 server is hosting the DNS too.